# loop the column of the dataframe

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2

I have a question of loop the column name in a dataframe. However, it does not work for some reason.

Error return as "Error: Only strings can be converted to symbols"

```
   vars <- colnames(DO4)
   varslist = vars[c(1:2,4:8)]

for (i in varslist) {
 DO5 <- DO4 %>%
    group_by (Primary.UY, !!!rlang::syms(names(.)[i])) %>%
    summarise(tot_inc=sum(Incurred),
            tot_clmcount=sum(clmcount),
            tot_prem=sum(prem)) %>%
    mutate(LR=tot_inc/tot_prem,
           clmfreq=tot_clmcount/tot_prem*1000)
    
  
 
k <- colnames(DO5)
l = k[c(2)]


 
 for (j in l) {
       
      
      ## LR
      
       plotgg <- ggplot(DO5, aes(x=DO5[, j],y=LR)) +
            geom_bar(stat='identity')+
            ggtitle("LR ")+
            labs(x = j) +
            theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, size=8))+
            facet_grid(cols = vars(Primary.UY))+
            scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) paste0(x, "%"))+
            coord_flip()
        print(plotgg)
        }
    }
```

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
Data example:--try to plot X axis: Group; Y axis: Incurred/Prem

UY     PolNo Incurred Prem   Group Clmcount
2011   1      1000    10000  A      2
2011   2      2000    10000  A      4
2012   3      3000    30000  A      4
2012   4      2000    15000  B      1
2012   5      5000    90000  C      2
2013   6      1000    10000  B      4
```

Comment: You have two loops which one gives you the error? It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: You are already looping over the column names. Therefore `names(.)[i]` will return `NA`. Try with `!!!syms(i)` instead.

Comment: Vielen Dank Stefan! Yes, you have spot on the right error. It is the !!!syms part return the error.  It returns "Error: Only strings can be converted to symbols". However, after I have changed to the one you suggested it is still return error "Error in is.finite(x) : default method not implemented for type 'list'"....how to revise this part?

Comment: Hi Ronak, I have tried the .data[[i]] which you suggested in the other post, it returns error "Error in is.finite(x) : default method not implemented for type 'list'"...